# hiding content on an MVC view after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC password reset form where the user enters their email and a password reset link is sent to them.
What I want to achieve is that when the email has successfully been sent then in the view I want to hide the email input box and display a message to say that an email has been sent.
What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be argued that you should send a user to a completely different view once the email has been sent.

So in your code, once you have posted the form to your Controller, return the View of a confirmation page.

e.g.

```
if ( email.sent) {
    Return View("Confirmation");
}
else{
    Return View(emailModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this in the end: -

```
@if (ViewBag.okay == "true"){

    @:Thanks, a password reset link Has been emailed to you.


}else{
    <form method="post">
        Please enter your email address <input type="text" name="email" id="email" style="width: 200px;" /> <input type="submit" value="Send Password Reset Link" />
    </form>
}
```